# OMP library not found in /usr/local/lib via cmake

Tags: macos, cmake, clang, openmp

MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1, Apple M2

I'm trying to compile [GMSHFEM](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/fem/-/wikis/Compilation) via CMake. The program uses OpemMP, which caused some problems (since CMake can't find HomeBrew's OpenMP by default), but eventually, I solved these by copying the appropriate header files "omp.h" to /usr/local/include and library "libomp.dylib" to /usr/local/lib.

```
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -Xclang -fopenmp (found version "5.0") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "5.0")
```

Now, CMake can find OpenMP, but on running the 'make' command, I get the error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libgmshfem.dylib
ld: library 'omp' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't understand this. How can the omp library not be found if it's sitting in /usr/local/lib?

Opening CMakeCache.txt, I see:

```
//CXX compiler flags for OpenMP parallelization
OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-Xclang -fopenmp

//Path to a file.
OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/include

//CXX compiler libraries for OpenMP parallelization
OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES:STRING=libomp

//Path to a library.
OpenMP_libomp_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib
```

So, it appears that everything is in order. What am I doing wrong that clang can't link with the omp library properly?

Comment: Are you linking to `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX`?

Comment: No, it doesn't appear that I am. Is that required?

Comment: Yes. Please read the docs. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenMP.html

Comment: Linking to imported targets is the best way to do things in CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by pointing GMSHFEM's CMake instructions to the correct homebrew directories, which for me were:

```
  elseif(APPLE AND EXISTS "/opt/homebrew/lib")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include")
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS "-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib -lomp")
    set_config_option("OpenMP[Homebrew,M1]" HAVE_OPENMP)
  else()
```

For some reason, the pre-compiled OpenMP libraries I downloaded and placed in /usr/local/lib may have been the issue, although my knowledge of OpenMP and CMake is extremely limited.

@Alex Reinking appears to be correct, but it looks like GMSHFEM was indeed already linking to OpenMP_CXX.